# Android: Enable touch sound on View

Tags: android, events, audio, touch, listadapter

Usually on the Android OS when something is touched like a button or list item it makes a touch tone or sound.  I have a custom made AdapterView ([DevsmartLib](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android/blob/master/devsmartlib/src/com/devsmart/android/ui/HorizontalListView.java)) that basically creates a horizontal list view for me, however, none of the items make sounds when touched.  I'm wondering if anyone knows what settings or options control whether a touch ends up triggering a sound or not.  Any help or pointers are highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

I think [this SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3905651/645270) answers your questions.

You can use the xml attribute [soundEffectsEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:soundEffectsEnabled), or its corresponding java method, and after that you can play sound effects using [Sound Effect Constants](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SoundEffectConstants.html) in the [playSoundEffect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#playSoundEffect%28int%29) method. This could also be done with MediaPlayer, but I don't think that's the kind of sound you want.

This [developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) on multimedia might help if you want other kinds of sound.