# If using MediaPlayer to play Button click sound, what happens to default click sound?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-button

For the record, I am not asking how to play a sound programmatically with the MediaPlayer.  I know how to do that quite well.

I first searched how to replace the default click sound of a Button in the XML.  But I have not found out if that is possible.  Most answers suggest to use the MediaPlayer to play a sound effect somewhere in/from the onClick() event of the Button, so I assume that's the best way to go?

If I use the MediaPlayer to play a sound when a Button is clicked, do I have to disable the default click sound as well, or will both play, or will Android just know to ignore the default click sound?  Should I call setSoundEffectsEnabled(false) on the Button before I play my own sound?

It seems very strange to me that I can't just replace the default click sound of a Button (is it possible to do that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set  `android:soundEffectsEnabled=false` in your theme defined into your `res/styles.xml`

or programatically:

```
myButton.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Basically, I was looking for a way to override all Button click sound effects very easily with my same effect (for 25 buttons across 6 Fragments).  I found the only way to do this was like you said, disable in XML by default for each Button, and then play my own in onClick() for each Button.  Kinda lame, Android.

Answer (score 0):

you may wish to check this link as well: [Playing sound effect (CLICK/NAVIGATION_RIGHT) for button clicks - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905651/playing-sound-effect-click-navigation-right-for-button-clicks-android)

seems that sound effects are kept as `android.view.SoundEffectConstants.<value>`

correspondingly, there might be a way of adding your own custom sound

it is all about passing the value of sound effect you'd like to hear, into `<view variable>.playSoundEffect(<sound effect value>);` so you may try to add your sound into `res` and call that method with its R value

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry, I was aware of this as well.  But this is a good answer to my misleading question :)