# Android Tap sound inside a webview posible?

Tags: android, audio, webview, click, user-experience

Thanks in advance

I'm developing an hybrid app, native/webview. I need to know if it is possible to make the same sound that occurs "on click" in native but inside webview in a link.

It is all for get the same experience user on the webview.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, there is no such setting. But you can try to do it manually: catch all clicks by JS, and play sound. For example (using Js interface):

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void playSound(){
    webView.playSoundEffect(0);
}
```

About playSoundEffect(0) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905651/playing-sound-effect-click-navigation-right-for-button-clicks-android).

Comment: Thanks. it is how I suspected.